# Flutter with AWS CloudBuild fails to compile apk

Tags: android, flutter, aws-codebuild

Gday!

What I'm trying to do is to create CI/CD pipeline for Flutter android application using AWS Developer tools.
But I couldn't manage to compile apk package using AWS Codebuild. Could you please help we out.

Setup is pretty simple.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTaKD.png)

For simplicity I took flutter HelloWorld dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      android: 29
      java: openjdk8
    commands:
      - pwd
pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pre Build started on `date`
      - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
      - export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
      - flutter precache
      - flutter doctor
build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - flutter build apk
      - ls -al
post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
```

CodeBuild process succeeds but each time after run it creates new random name output artifact but not .apk file.

I have tried several combinations like, but they end up with an error.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/app-release.apk"
```

AND

```
artifacts:
  type: apk
  files:
    - "**/*"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYssO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. I managed to compile apk file after I changed working directory to helloworld.

Correct buildspec.yml should look like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      android: 29
      java: openjdk8
    commands:
      - pwd
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo Pre Build started on `date`
    - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
    - export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
    - flutter precache
    - flutter doctor
  build:
    commands:
    - cd helloworld
    - pwd
    - ls -al
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - flutter build apk
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
  - helloworld/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
  discard-paths: yes
```